# Accessing a non-accessible class from a base class which it is visible to

Tags: c#, .net

Just out of interest, I'm currently try to get a grasp of the MS Workflow Foundation even though, it seems to be running out of support.

The Internal Workings of a few classes are deeply rooted in the Framework and so, If you try to build custom Workflow-Flow-Control classes and you look into the reference source they reference to classes which are only visible to internal Microsoft implementations. An example:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/NativeActivity.cs

Is a class which you take as base and write custom implementations from it. If you look further in the source:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/Statements/Flowchart.cs

This is a reference example of how Microsoft implemented their Activity "FlowChart".

There is a line like

```
this.variables = new ValidatingCollection<Variable>
```

Which is to be found here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Internals/System/Runtime/Collections/ValidatingCollection.cs

This namespace (or compliation result?) has accessibility constraints like:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("System.Activities, PublicKey=...")]
```

Found in:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Internals/AssemblyInfo.cs

So my question is, if you inherit from a class, in this case `NativeActivity` which is found
in an allowed namespace (or compliation result?) for the given class `ValidatingCollection` are you then somehow supposed
to also use the internal implementations like `ValidatingCollection` or not? Thanks =)

Comment: As the cost of a small performance hit, you can like call any of those methods or types with reflection (if you really needed them)

Comment: Probably yes, thanks for the suggestion, I dont know if the designer evaluates the methods on runtime of itself for checking the correctness of your workflow before it can get published. This would maybe cause problems if they are called by reflection, but the question is of a more general nature :)

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, if you inherit from a class, in this case
> NativeActivity which is found in an allowed namespace (or compliation
> result?) for the given class ValidatingCollection are you then somehow
> supposed to also use the internal implementations like
> ValidatingCollection or not?

No, you don't. There can be no use of `ValidatingCollection` in the public API of `NativeActivity.cs` to begin with because the assembly would not even compile if there were; MS would get an "Inconsistent accesibility" compile time error if that were the case.

So, if there is no usage of said helper class in the public API you are trying to extend (that includes protected members) why would you need to use it?

`ValidatingCollection` is an implementation detail you don't need to worry about.

Comment: I thought of building similar function oriented on the Microsoft implementation and so taking some snippets out of it :) But if this is not allowed then there is another way.